# Does Microsoft Expression Blend leave any trace behind in the code?

Tags: c#, mvvm, expression-blend

I have inherited a code from a prev. employee of our company that I need to maintain. Since he has Microsoft Blend installed in his machine and chose a MVVM architecture to build the code, now I am wondering is there anywhere in the code, Xaml or somewhere that I might look and find out that Blend registered his name which may show UI is designed by Blend.
If so, then it's easier to continue and use this tool to make modifications to the code.

I know you might be asking, just go check the latest projects. But the situation is, the Blend is expired/unregistered and now I don't want to purchase or install a new trial to find out.

Comment: Check if there is crazy/random indentation in the XAML -- that's a Blend tip-off.

Comment: Why do you care about that? in WPF you type your XAML by hand (unless you're creating custom control styles or special effects or custom shapes, where Blend can really be helpful) If you don't want to spend money on Blend just type your XAML in Visual Studio, or even Notepad.

Comment: @HighCore, since this is a very big and well developed code it would be easier to go with the same approach in regards to make modification. (It's not being fussy or something. Mainly taking the best and shortest approach. thats all)

Answer (score 0):

As @McGarnagle said, it dropped the dime and I remembered that any time I added something in Blend and built the project I needed to come back and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> the code to fix the format/indentation.
However, the guy who generated the code might have corrected the formatting as he went forward with blend.

Thanks for the comment.